# C++ map element doesn't get erased if I refer to it

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

Playing around with C++ standard library's std::map class, and noticed if I erase an element, then attempt to reference it (the commented out line in the code below), the element will come back with a value of 0. Is this expected? Do you really have to use a find function to  access an element without accidentally creating one if it doesn't exist?

compiler setup: I'm compiling on osx 10.8.3 with g++ i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

```
using namespace std;

map<int,int> myMap;
map<int,int>::iterator it;

myMap[1] = 5;

for (it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';

printf("map test result: %d\n", myMap[1]);

it = myMap.find(1);
myMap.erase( it );

// If I uncomment this it will cause a 0 value to occur at key 1.
//printf("map test result: %d\n", myMap[1]);

if (myMap.find(1) == myMap.end())
    puts("element key 1 is null, ok");
else
    puts("element @ key 1 exists, error");

if (myMap.empty())
    puts("map is empty");
else
    puts("map is not empty, error");

for (it=myMap.begin(); it!=myMap.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
```

Just to clarify, if I run this with the second printf line commented, it runs as expected:

```
1 => 5
map test result: 5
element key 1 is null, ok
map is empty
```

If I run with the line uncommented, the access of myMap[1] in the printf statement creates another element, and leaves this result:

```
1 => 5
map test result: 5
map test result: 0
element @ key 1 exists, error
map is not empty, error
1 => 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is what `operator[]` of `std::map` is supposed to do. From the Standard (C++11, §23.5.4.3):

> ```
> mapped_type& operator[](const key_type& k);
> mapped_type& operator[](key_type&& k);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Effects: If the unordered_map does not already contain an element whose key is equivalent to k, the first operator inserts the value `value_type(k, mapped_type())` and the second operator inserts the value `value_type(std::move(k), mapped_type())`.

Note that this would happen even if the element had never been inserted and then erased. Element access using `operator[]` simply inserts fresh, default-constructed values when you apply it to non-existing keys.

If you don't want this, best use the `find` function of `std::map`. That will return an `end`-iterator if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. In addition to reading the specification, you can infer this from the type signature:

```
T& operator[] (const key_type& k);
```

It can't tell if you'll end up assigning to the key because `operator =` is called on its return value, after the `[]` operator has already finished executing. There is also no way for the method to represent an empty value: it returns a reference, not a pointer.

Comment: +1 (although, in theory, the map could return a reference to some sort of dummy element. It would be strange design, but it's not impossible).

Comment: The way it works now makes it perfect for counters or maps of containers. map[key]++ or map[key].push_back(value) is much cleaner than the equivalent in languages which don't do this (such as java)

Comment: @jogojapan Indeed! This can of course be checked by seeing if `T` is the same `T` that you give in `std::map<T>`.